# Solve a system of non linear equations over GF

Tags: finite-field

I have the following set of equations:

$$M_{1}=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$$

$$M_{2}=\frac{y_2-y_0}{x_2-x_0}$$

$M_1, M_2,  x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2,$ are known and they are chosen from a $GF(2^m)$. I want to find  $x_0,y_0$

Does the previous set of equations is solvable?

And more...

If I have the following set of equations:

$$M_1=\frac{k_1-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_1-x_0))}{(l_1-x_0)(l_1-x_1)}$$

$$M_2=\frac{k_2-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_2-x_0))}{(l_2-x_0)(l_2-x_1)}$$

$$M_3=\frac{k_3-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_3-x_0))}{(l_3-x_0)(l_3-x_1)}$$

$$M_4=\frac{k_4-(y_0+(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0})(l_4-x_0))}{(l_4-x_0)(l_4-x_1)}$$

where $x_0,y_0 x_1,y_1$ are the unknown GF elements.

As Dilip Sarwate clarified the set of equations is constructed by someone who " chose three distinct x0,x1,x2, as well as y0,y1,y2, then computed M1, M2, and finally revealed $M_1,M_2,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ but not $x_0,y_0$ to us" i.e. it is known that the system has solution.

My question was: 
Can I recover the $x_0, y_0$ or in the second set of equations can I recover $x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1$ and generally in nonlinear sets to recover the respective $x_i, y_i$  by the provided info, on a GF? and the main point of my question: Does the fact that the set of equations is defined on a Galois Field impose any difficulties to find its solution?

I was not sure that it is possible to compute the solution of the  problem with the aforementioned parameters on a Galois Field.

As Dilip Sarwate stated in his answer the solution of the previous problem can be recovered for linear and nonlinear equations.

Comment: Since you are working in a field, and presuming all values are defined, both your equations can be rewritten as linear equations. You got two linear equations with two unknown, so the answer is "yes".

Comment: If the set of equations is larger (as in the edited question) the answer still remains the same?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, the equations in your edited question are not linear. If the known values are selected randomly, there might be zero solutions or multiple solutions.

Comment: Why multiple? If it wasnt over GF would be finite or not?
It is a matter of congruence?

Comment: Do you mean as a quadratic has zero or two roots?

Comment: What if at your initial equations you only know `$y_1-y_0$` and not the actual values of '$y_0$' and '$y_1$' and the same for the second equation? Is the system still solvable?

Comment: I thinks that it is unsolvable because there would be 3 unknown variables $$a=y_1-y_0, b=y_2-y_0, and x_0$$. 
What's are you tring to ssay with your question?

Comment: I was just wondering if there are infinite solutions if you only know the difference and not the values or there is  still a weakness and someone can solve the system with some approximations

Comment: i think that as you stated the problem, the set of equations is unsovalble. It is different to know a,c than knowing k=a-c.

Comment: Could you edit your question so (1) it is clear how it relates to cryptography?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for Mathematics.SE

Answer (score 5):

There have been extensive comments by the OP on this question as well as [a related one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9295/819) and its answers and the consensus
don't seem to be converging at all to anything sensible.

> Broadly speaking, the field in which we are operating influences
>   the answer to the question of whether a system of equations has
>   solutions or not to some extent, but not in the ways that the OP
>   thinks it does. Whether we are operating in a prime field or an
>   extension of a prime field (what the OP calls gf or GF) has relatively
>   little to do with the matter. In particular, for linear equations,
>   the general theory of linear equations over a field
>   usually has more to say about the matter than the identity of the
>   field.

As Henrick Hellström has pointed out in a comment on the question,
the first set of equations in the OP's question can be converted
into a pair of linear equations in the unknowns $x_0$ and $y_0$,
say
$$\begin{align} a_{11}x_0 + a_{12}y_0 &= b_1\\
a_{21}x_0 + a_{22}y_0 &= b_2\end{align}$$
where the $a_{ij}$ and the $b_k$ are *functions* of
the known quantities $M_1, M_2, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$.
I refuse to calculate and state explicitly what the $a_{ij}$ 
and the $b_k$ are in terms of the known quantities. I will
differ from Henrick slightly, though, in that I do not think
that these equations are solvable for each and every choice of
$M_1, M_2, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$. This has *nothing* to do with
whether these quantities belong to GF$(2^m)$ or GF$(p^m)$ for
$p > 2$ or GF$(p)$ and everything to do with basic linear
equation theory: the matrix might be *singular*
for some choices of $M_1, M_2, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ in which
case we get multiple solutions rather than a unique solution,
or the matrix might be singular *and* the equations might be
 *inconsistent* in which case no solution exists.

All this, however, as well as the OP's questions about other
equations is irrelevant in the context of Shamir's secret
sharing scheme which is referenced in the 
*[other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9295/819)*
but not in this one but which I believe is the reason for
these questions.

If someone *chose* three distinct $x_0, x_1, x_2$, as well
as $y_0, y_1, y_2$, then computed $M_1$, $M_2$, and finally
revealed $M_1, M_2, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$, but not $x_0, y_0$
to us, then we can find $x_0$ and $y_0$ from the given
relationships, and inconsistency is not an issue.  Note the
requirement that $x_0, x_1, x_2$ be distinct which allows
the unnamed someone to avoid the heartbreak of
division by $0$ when computing $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Similar remarks apply to the nonlinear equations in the
OP's question as well.

Comment: When I tried to solve a system of quadratics I found out that ${x_0}^{2}$ has come up. I think that I should have to compute the square root of the x0. Is it possible in GF?

Comment: It seems that these questions will _never_ converge... In a finite field GF$(2^m)$, _every_ element has a square root (not true in GF$(p^m)$ for $p > 2$) and the square root can be found easily. One way that _always_ works is to _square_ the element $m-1$ times: $$\sqrt{x_0} = \underbrace{((\cdots ((x)^2)^2\cdots)^2)^2} ~~~ m-1 ~\text{squarings}$$ More efficient methods use the properties of the irreducible polynomial used to define the field, or log tables, etc.

Comment: Ok. The same stands for e.g.$\sqrt[3]{x_0}$ or more generally $\sqrt[n]{x_0}$ ? I am asking because in some cases the system may have 10 unknonws and 10 equations. Thus, powers such as ${x_0}^{10}$ will come up and the computation of $\sqrt[10]{x_0}$ will be needed.

Comment: Sigh....   No, you cannot use the idea mentioned in my previous comment for square roots for other roots in GF$(2^m)$.  The kinds of equations you are looking to solve seem to be closely related to Lagrange interpolation and thus should not need $n$-th roots (or square roots for that matter) in the solution process, but if you feel that they do, then to each his own.

Comment: Lagrange interpolation does not need n-th roots, but if you try to solve the problem posted in the question I think that they may be needed. Once again, Can I compute roots $\sqrt[1/n]{x}$?

Comment: Are my questions that strange???

Answer (score 0):

The first question is solvable:

$$x_0=x_1+(y_0-y_1)M_1^{-1}$$
$$x_0=x_2+(y_0-y_2)M_2^{-1}$$

So
$$y_0=\frac{M_1M_2(x_2-x_1)+M_2y_1-M_1y_2}{M_2-M_1}.$$

And about the second one, we have a similar method.