# Why does Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme need a finite field?

Tags: finite-field, secret-sharing

I read ampersand's question ["Necessity for finite field arithmetic and the prime number p in Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/necessity-for-finite-field-arithmetic-and-the-prime-number-p-in-shamirs-secret), where he asked why Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme uses arithmetic in a finite field of prime order.

The answers to that question explain that a prime field is *not* necessary for Shamir's scheme, but, rather, that any finite field can be used.  However, they don't really address the *other* part of the question, namely **why do we need a finite field at all?**  Couldn't we just use, say, ordinary integer arithmetic instead?

Can someone please explain (in the simplest possible manner) the reason that Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme uses finite field arithmetic?

Comment: Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme uses finite field arithmetic because one can easily $\hspace{1.3 in}$ sample elements almost-uniformly from a finite field. $\:$

Comment: Thats the only reason? It has nothing to do with security?

Comment: Almost-uniform sampling is needed for security. $\:$

Comment: From at practical point of view, computers couldn't perform real field arithmetic anyway, since it can only represent real values approximately. By using a finite field, you are able to ensure the algorithm will output exact values.

Comment: For calculating the interpolation polynomial one needs its coefficients to be elements of a field. Sampling random values uniformly from an infinite field is not possible, so you have to take a finite field.

Comment: @RickyDemer It is almost as easy (if not equally easy) to sample almost-uniformly from a finite _ring_ as from a finite _field._ So, surely the ease of almost-uniform sampling cannot be the reason for use of a finite field.

Comment: It's not the reason for a finite _field_, but it is the reason for a _finite_ field. $\:$

Answer (score 6):

The reason that a *field* must be used in Shamir's reconstruction scheme is
that the calculations used in the reconstruction need to divide one "number"
by another, and division is not defined in $\mathbb Z$, the set of integers:
$\frac{m}{n}$ is not necessarily a member of $\mathbb Z$.
So, why not use $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb Q$ which can be "implemented" in
terms of pairs of integers? The answer again is that computers use
floating-point arithmetic which is not the same as real arithmetic, or
integer arithmetic which is, if we ignore overflow and underflow, effectively
modular arithmetic in $\mathbb Z_{2^m}$ which is not a field but a ring.
A more subtle issue is that the Shamir's scheme implicitly assumes that
a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in a field does not
have more than $n$ roots in the field, which property is not true in rings.
For example, the polynomial $x^2 - 1$ has four roots $\pm 1, \pm 4$
in the ring $\mathbb Z_{15}$ instead of the two $\pm 1$
that it has in a field such as $\mathbb Z_{17} = \mathbb F_{17}$.

As a concrete example of what might happen with integer arithmetic as
implemented on a general-purpose computer, consider
[this formula for secret reconstruction](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8262/819)
$$s_0 = (-1)^k (x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_k) \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{y_i}{x_i\cdot c_i}$$
taken from another answer of mine.
Here, $s_0$ is the secret that is reconstructed from shares $(x_i,y_i)$
(that is, $y_i = s(x_i)$) and
$$c_i = (x_i-x_1)(x_i-x_2)\cdots(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})\cdots(x_i-x_k).$$
Now consider the case where the $k$ shareholders who have
gathered to reconstruct the secret all happen to have $x_i$ an odd integer.
Then, $c_i$ is an even integer -- in fact, a multiple of $2^{k-1}$ --
and so $\frac{y_i}{x_i\cdot c_i}$ is *not necessarily* an integer. However, the sum
$s_0$ will work out to be an integer.
With ordinary integer arithmetic on a computer, the fractional parts
of  $\frac{y_i}{x_i\cdot c_i}$, if any, will
be lost when the integer division indicated is computed, and thus
$s_0$ will not be computed correctly. This is not to say that one could 
not manage this issue
with careful programming that works around the problem, but we also have
to deal with the possibility that the computations might cause overflow
or underflow which also needs to be worked around.  In any case, there
can be problems that arise because the polynomials re-constructed
via Lagrange interpolation are not necessarily the same as the ones used to
construct the secret originally. Foe example, both $x^2-1$ and
$(x-1)(x-4) = x^2-5x+4$ have roots $1$ and $4$ in $Z_{15}$. Since
we don't know ahead of time *which* shares will be available for
reconstruction, we cannot be sure whether we will reconstruct the
correct polynomial in the Lagrange interpolation process.
Thus, whether the secret recovery process will work as claimed
in a ring is an open question. That the process *will* work in
a field is guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks Dilip for your answer.

Have you got any advice for this problem?

http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9294/solve-a-system-of-equations-over-gf

Comment: Your answer about the roots of $$x^2-1$$ puzzled me. If I ave a set of equations let's say with 3 equations and 3 unknowns, where the knowns and unknown variables are  GF elements I cannot be sure that I ll find the right answer?It depends on the irreducible polynomial? I am referring to GF generated by ir. polynomials

Comment: If the three equations have a unique solution in a field whether it is a prime field (integers modulo a prime $p$) or an extension field (what you seem to be referring to as "GF generated by ir. polynomials), then standard calculations will give the right answer. The choice of irreducible polynomial merely changes the names we give to elements of the extension field and so the answer might "look" different but it is still the same answer: all that has happened is that we are using a different _basis_ to represent the answer.

Comment: So, It can be solved?i.e If I know that the set is defined in such a way that there is a solution, this solution can be computed? the set had 4 equations does this change anything?If it is a bigger set e.g. 6 eq?Its the same?

Comment: @Herc11 My comment was with regard to your question about 3 equations and 3 unknowns in general and not about the specific equations in your question 9294.

Comment: But I would like to know if any set of e.g 8 unknows and 8 equations can be solved...

Comment: $$\begin{align}x+y+z&=1\\2x+2y+2z&=2\\3x+3y+3z&=3\end{align}$$ has **multiple solutions** but _not_ a _unique_ solution in _any_ field; $$\begin{align}x+y+z&=0\\2x+2y+2z&=1\\3x+3y+3z&=1\end{align}$$ has **no** solutions in any field because the equations are inconsistent.

Comment: Ok.The equations of question 9294 represent 4 polynomials where for each polynomial I know one point and the leading coefficient. I know that these 4 polynomials (quadraticks) have two common points. If I was working in R I could find their intersection points by solving that set. Is it possible in GF?there is a solution as i know that the 4 quad. have two common points. Sorry if i getting you tred...

Comment: Sorry I didn't make clear that the polynomials of the are of second degree not linear...I get  confused...

Comment: If the set of equations is constituted by polynomials of n-degree and there are $$2*n$$ such polynomials over R the set has a solution. I am thinking that over GF the set cant be solved because it is no possible to find $$(x)^{1/n}=???$$.

Comment: The [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Algebra) is not true in most fields, and is true **in no finite field**. (Each field has an extension where it is true, but those extensions are not finite anymore.) I think you are mixing your theorems up.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to remove the references to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. But isn't it true that if a degree-$n$ polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[x]$ does not have $n$ roots in the _finite_ field $\mathbb F_q$, then all its $n$ roots lie in a _finite_ extension field $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ where $m$ is some finite integer? Or are you saying that the roots lie in _no_ finite extension of $F_q$, and we must always go to nonfinite extensions?

Comment: So, finite fields are employed because it is guaranteed that the solution of the problem can be found? In rings  R,Q  is not possible even if the computations are tranformed to avoid computers' prblems like overflow and underflow?

Comment: Languages like Haskell use arbitrary size integers my default.

Comment: @PyRulez I did not know that but the fact is irrelevant to the discussion. We need inverses to exist

Comment: @DilipSarwate it also has ratios of integers.

Comment: It's worth noticing that Shamir secret-sharing does work over arbitrary finite rings as long as they have evaluation points $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_n$ such that every non-zero difference is invertible. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48928/shamir-secret-sharing-p-not-prime/96507#96507

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is probably to give an example of information leaked when using Shamir's secret sharing over the integers. Assume that we construct a low degree example, defining $q$ to be a linear polynomial with $q(0)=D$ and $q(1)=a_1$. By interpolation you find that: $$q(x)=(a_1-D)x+D.$$

Assume that you are given the share corresponding to evaluation at $2$, i.e. $q(2)$. You can see that $q(2)=2a_1-D$. Since $a_1$ and $D$ are integers, given this single share, you learn the parity of $D$.

Comment: Therefore, the selection of the shares uniformly is not the only security reason. However I didnt understand why you learn something about D's parity.
A more helpful example woule be if: $$f(x)=a_1x+D$$
and at 2 users the $$f(1)$$ and $$f(-1)$$ is assigned.
Then the two users could easily recover D by adding their shares.

Comment: @Herc11: Yes, but two users putting their shares together to recover the secret is part of the specifications (when using a linear polynomial).

Comment: Yes, you re right. About the parity of D?

Comment: Well, if $a_1$ is an integer, then $2a_1$ is even. So $2a_1-D$ is odd if and only if $D$ is odd. So the share $f(2)$ directly leaks the parity of $D$.

Comment: Ok nice! Is this the only security flaw of using integers?

Comment: No. $\:$ (In fact, that's a result of the integers not being a field, rather than a result $\hspace{1.56 in}$ of there being infinitely many integers.) $\;\;\;$