# Can Reed-Solomon codes work on infinite fields like $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: coding-theory

I am currently reading about RS codes. I see that they are using a Galois Fields (Finite Fields) as vector spaces. Is there any other particular reason other than the fact that they simplify binary arithmetic and for example in $GF(2^8)$ each byte can be considered as a vector? Can they work in vector spaces that are defined on infinite fields like $\mathbb{Q}$. Thanks in advance for your time.

PS: Sorry in advance if this isn't the right place to post this question, but I saw that both Math and Crypto StachExchanges have `coding-theory` tag.

Comment: In crypto, we generally don't work in $\mathbb{Q}$; for boring practical reasons, we prefer messages that can be expressed in a bounded number of bits.

Comment: We also like to be able to define a uniform probability distribution over a space!

Comment: What poncho and Mikero mention makes sense, and these are crucial reasons why we don't consider infinite algebraic structures in cryptography. However, just to satisfy your curiosity: Reed-Solomon codes can be easily applied over **any** field, no matter what size. In fact, they exist over **any ring**, no matter the size, as long as it contains a large enough "exceptional sequence" (e.g. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96507/13843).

Comment: However, Reed-Solomon codes on their own simply take a message and add some redundancy for decoding errors. Their use in cryptography, for example in Shamir secret-sharing, requires sampling uniformly random elements over this structure, which as Mikero mentioned is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can work, and under some channel noise conditions be useful for error correction coding in a continuous channel. This idea was originally due to Prof. Welch (of Welch-Berlekamp algorithm and Welch bound fame) who had unpublished lecture notes about it in the 1980s, and from an engineering point of view $\mathbb{C}$ was the obvious field to use, where the issue of existence of primitive roots of unity of any desired order $n$ is trivial, just take $\omega=\exp\{2 \pi i/n\}.$

As the comments pointed out, this is not so useful for cryptography, since the existence of uniform distributions are crucial for certain protocols. Of course, Reed-Solomon codes in their field evaluation formulation are intimately linked to Shamir secret sharing, say with threshold $t,$ but in a finite field setting for enabling no leakage of information if less than $t$ shares are known.